# Mixin Webpack error for SCSS on missing variable

Tags: webpack, sass

Fairly new to SCSS so bare with me...I was creating a function in a mixins SCSS file and when running gatsby develop I was given a SassError for an undedfined variable although the "variable" is a parameter:

[Webpack SassError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmWYo.png)

Any advice on how to fix this? Here's the structure of the beginning of the code used in _mixins.scss:

```
@use './units';

// Add transitions to attributes
@mixin transition($attrs, $speed: normal) {
  $res: "";

  // Multiple attributes
  @if type-of($attrs) == list {
    @each $attr in $attrs {
      $res: #{$res}, _makeTransition($attr, $speed);
    }
  }
  // One/no attribute
  @else {
    $res: _makeTransition($attr, $speed);
  }

  transition: $res;
}

@function _makeTransition($attr, $speed) {
  $res: all map-get(units.$speed, $speed) cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);

  // Attribute has default props
  @if type-of($attr) == string {
    $res: $attr map-get(units.$speed, $speed) cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  }
  // Attribute has custom props
  @else if type-of($attr) == map {
    $speed: if(map-has-key($attr, speed), map-get($attr, speed), $speed);
    $res: map-get($attr, name)
      map-get(units.$speed, $speed)
      cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  }

  @return $res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because it cannot find `$attr` in its scope

```
@if type-of($attrs) == list {
    /*     $attr is defined here in @each scope */
    @each $attr in $attrs {
        $res: #{$res}, _makeTransition($attr, $speed);
    }
}
@else {
    $res: _makeTransition($attr, $speed);
}
```

From your code, `$attr` is defined in the `@each` scope. However, it is referenced in the `@else` scope.

If I understand your code logic correctly, in the `@else` block, it should be `$attrs` (with an `s`) because it's not a list:

```
$res: _makeTransition($attrs, $speed);
```